# Error regarding entry point in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm getting the following error when I run docker-compose up:

```
 services.**.entrypoint must be a string
```

The Dockerfile has the following structure:

> version: '3'
>
> services:
>
> service1:
>
> ...
>
> entrypoint: []
>
> ...

I removed the entrypoint but then the service would close as soon as it starts. The dockerfile is mostly correct since it is used by everyone in the organization.

Docker Desktop -> Check for updates -> You're up to date.(Docker Desktop 3.5.1)

Comment: If your container has neither an entrypoint or a command, then it doesn't do anything and you should expect it to exit right away. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm using the file to create a docker image for a raspbian environment. The idea is to use it as an environment for a PyCharm project.

Comment: @JeanPicard There are no logs. I get the error immediately after docker-compose up

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

This seems to be bug of Docker Desktop 3.5.1, when I update it to 3.5.2, It fixed.

---

### Setting empty entrypoint is useful

Setting empty entrypoint is useful in case when run command in container without entrypoint.

For example, [Developing inside a Container using Visual Studio Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) often use independent command from entrypoint:
[Create a development container using Visual Studio Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container#_use-docker-compose)

```yaml
# Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

When base image has entrypoint, it's useful to set it empty to run its command:

```yaml
entrypoint: []
# Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

Comment: For now, I'm using v 3.3 to run the code. It's working.